# Replace working on Ubuntu Chrome but not on Mac Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, replace

I'm using this code as a mask to allow only alphabetical chars, with accent included, on the `input` field.

```
$("#field").on('input', function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zà-ÿ\s]/ig, '');
  });
```

On ubuntu chrome it work properly, allowing char with accent or not. But on Mac chrome it not allowing chars with accent.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you try using `/[a-z\u0080-\u00ff\s]/ig` instead of `/[^a-zà-ÿ\s]/ig`. I doubt it will fix the issue tho. Might be an issue with you Mac's Chrome encoding settings ? This is a bit weird ...

Comment: Didn't worked, its very weird